# Underderstanding the solution of problem #2.1.4 in AT.

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra, exact-sequence

The problem and its solution are given below:

> [image]
>   [image]

**My questions are:**

1-Why the edge $c$ in the drawing takes this direction?

2-Are we considering the sequence of chain complexes exact?

3-In the third line from below,in the calculation of $H_{1}(X)$ in the numerator, why is $<a,b,c> = <a,b, a+b-c>$, specifically why the third coordinate became like this? Also why $<a,b> = \mathbb{Z}^2$, what is the meaning of $<a,b>$, are they numbers?

Could anyone help me answer these questions, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2. Are we considering the sequence of chain complexes exact?

No.

1-Why the edge c in the drawing takes this direction?

There is a standard way of assigning the direction of arrow, which is from lower index to hight. The vertex where two arrows are coming can be thought $v2$ of the simplex $[v0 v1 v2]$

In the third line from below, in the calculation of H1(X) in the numerator, why is =, specifically why the third coordinate became like this? Also why =Z2, what is the meaning of , are they numbers?

For drawing part: Let  [$v_0 v_1 v_2$] is a 2-simplex. Then on every edge, we assign a direction/orientation from lower index to higher index. In fact, it's a consequence of the definition of the boundary map.  Now,  choose orientation for the $2$ simplex  [$v_0 v_1 v_2$]. Let's denote the edge [$v_0 v_1$] , [$v_1v_2$], [$v_0 v_2$] by $ a, b, c$ respectively. Then the edge $a$ gets orrientation from the vertex $v_0$ to $v_1$, and $b$ gets orrintation from $v_1$ to $v_2$ and $c$ gets orrientaion from $v_0$ to $v_2$. Then Identify the three edges according to problem statement. It'll give the right picture. I hope this helps.

Think about the basis of a vector space. It will give you the main motivation. I hope this helps.

Comment: Note that if the sequence were exact, we would always get the trivial homology for all n. More specifically, to define homology, we the chain complex needs not to be exact.

Comment: why is <a,b,c>=<a,b,a+b−c>? Think about some basic linear algebra. We can span $R^2$ both by ($e_1, e_2$) and  ($e_1, e_1 +e_2$). I hope this helps.

Comment: $<a,b>=Z^2$ , what is the meaning of <a,b>, are the numbers? Well, the group $Z^2$ here is the free abelian group generated by the two generators namely $a$ and $b$. Finally, $a$ and $b$ are not numbers. They are called chain. In this particular case, they are just 1-chain. If you clearly read the definition of homology groups, everything will be clear. You can read the first 4 pages of Hatcher's chapter 2. Good Luck!

Comment: "More specifically, to define homology, we the chain complex needs not to be exact." That's wrong. Homology is a measure of how non-exact a sequence is. An exact sequence has homology, the homology is just trivial.

Comment: Your explanation for the part of the drawing is not clear also your explanation of the first part of the third question is not clear .... could you clarify please?

Comment: Can you please see the explanation that I wrote for the drawing? Is it helpful?

Comment: I edited my answer and something on the drawing part. Arthur, you're correct. Whenever we have an exact sequence of chain complexes,  the homology group is trivial for any degree. That's why I said exactness is not needed. I did not mean that we don't need exact sequences. Anyway, sorry for the misinterpretation.

Comment: For the group generation part: Since homology groups are free, they have generators. You can generate the same group with different generators.  For example, $Z$ can be generated by $1$ and $ -1$.  That means $Z$ = <$1$> and $Z$ = <$-1$>.

Comment: In the calculation of H1(X) in the numerator, why is <a,b,c>=<a,b,a+b−c>? First of all, equality is clear because both generate a rank $3$ -free abelian group. Roughly speaking: you can think them like vector space spaning, which is not technically correct because here the underlying set of coefficients is $Z$, set of integer, and which is not a field. If you have some basic idea of modules, then it would be crystal clear. Most importantly, we change our generating sets so that the quotient operation becomes easy. In homology computation, you'll see this again & again.

Comment: but why the generator $c$ is the same as the generator $a+b-c$@MMM?

Comment: Good question. Notice that the image of $d_2$ is generated by $a+b−c $. To compute $H_1(X)$ you need to quotient by the image of  $d_2$ = <$a+b−c $>. So, they changed one of the generators. In fact, you can do the same thing with $a$ or $b$.